# Application Insights SDK or Azure Monitor OpenTelemetry Distro?

Tags: c#, monitoring, azure, telemetry

I am new to `Azure` and `Observability` worlds.
I will be building a .net app that follows `Observability` principles, to be further analyzed in `Azure Monitor`.
I wonder which c# telemetry library should I be picking.
[MS's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable?tabs=aspnetcore#whats-the-current-release-state-of-features-within-the-azure-monitor-opentelemetry-distro) state `OpenTelemetry` is the future and recommended choice, but it currently lacks implementation of features covered by `Application Insights` such as `Profiler` and `Snapshot Debugger`.

**Pros for using OpenTelemetry's nuget (among others)**:

> OpenTelemetry SDKs tend to be more performant at scale than their
> predecessors, the Application Insights SDKs.

**Cons**:

- Lack of support for features (that otherwise feel **essential**) like `Profiler`, `Snapshot Debugger`.

Any remarks/inputs ?